# What does "Add Service Reference" really do?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, message

Forgive me if the question is incoherent.

I find WCF really complicated. Moreover, different ways to do the same thing make a beginner even more befuddled, like hard-code a host vs config file, or hard-code a client vs add service reference. (Am I feeling right?)
I think it would be helpful to try to go through the process with code in a primitive way. No service reference, no config file.

Maybe I can put it this way: If the service is running on another machine (or my machine pretending another machine), what are the minimum things it has to provide beside an address for some one to consume it?
And how can I consume it with code?

Answer (score 4):

Add Service Reference parses the WSDL of the service to import the service contract, and potentially any referenced domain types, into the client's representation (in this case, C#). It generates a proxy which exposes a C# interface that represents the service contract. The proxy is a namespace and set of classes with methods to call each service method for the particular endpoint.

In short it takes service contract metadata and reifies it to C#.

You can also manually generate the proxy with 'svcutil.exe'

```
svcutil http://server.com/FooService/FooService.svc /out:FooProxy.cs
```

Or to include generation of the app.config as well

```
svcutil http://server.com/FooService /out:FooProxy.cs /config:App.config
```

Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" does that for you, plus adds the new files to your project.